# Demographics and interests reports in Google universal analytics

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, demographics

I have an issue with Google Analytics, can't seem to find a guide how to activate Demographics and Interests reports. 
I am using the new version of analytics (Universal Analytics) and the script code looks something like this:

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
```

But [the guide I found on google's page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819948?hl=sv) is for the old version (Classis Analytics).

Does anyone know how I can activate this on Universal Analytics?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on this page: 
http://online-behavior.com/analytics/demographics

This is not available with Universal Analytics yet.